# Fix Typescript error when customizing MuiDataGrid in createTheme

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I want to customize my DataGridPro table (MUI component) in the theme. However, when I MuiDataGrid to components object, I get a TS error:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'MuiDataGrid' does not exist in type 'Components'.ts(2322)
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/datagriddemo-material-demo-forked-vedcm

How do I fix the error? I spent 2 hours looking everywhere without success.

Answer (score 15):

I got answer to this question on MUI github issue page: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/1755#issuecomment-945650984

The solution is to import theme augmentation like so:

```
import type {} from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro/themeAugmentation';
```

as described in: https://mui.com/components/data-grid/getting-started/#typescript

Comment: using themeAugmentation for datagrid and for datepicker from mui-x-date / mui-x-data-grid doest work =/ should they both be imported as 'import type {}' ?