# Override Theme for MUI DatePicker Pro

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to add CSS changes to my theme for MUIX components and it seems like I am getting type errors. For this example we will use for DatePicker Component. According to the [docs](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#customization) I should be able to do the following:

```
import { create theme, ThemeOptions } from ‘@mui/material/styles’;

const MyTheme: ThemeOptions = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiPickersToolbar: {
      …
    }
  }
})
```

But the `MuiPickersToolbar` lights up red with a type error:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and `MuiPickersToolbar` does not exist in type ‘Components<Omit<Theme, “components”>>’
```

In my package.json I have the following peerDependencies

```
“@emotion/react”: “>=11.11.3”,
“@mui/material”: “>=5.15.7”,
“@mui/x-date-pickers-pro”: “>=6.19.3”
```

Not sure what I am missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following import:

```
import type {} from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/themeAugmentation';
```

You can find the documentation about this here:

https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/base-concepts/#typescript

Related answer: [Fix Typescript error when customizing MuiDataGrid in createTheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608945/fix-typescript-error-when-customizing-muidatagrid-in-createtheme/69615652#69615652)